# Upload records to Facebook Custom audience, no error, but no audit history either

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making the following call to a custom audience I created via the API with the same token. This call worked last week but not FB returns an HTTP 200 but nothing happens to the audience.

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{{my audience id}}/users?access_token={{FacebookAppToken}}`

```
payload={ 
"schema": [ 
  "EXTERN_ID", 
  "FN", 
  "LN", 
  "EMAIL" 
], 
"data": [ 
  [ 
    "ExternId123xdf",
    "22b074c0fdb3b9e315df7e94ca7c52cbcfe41be6f01d1d03189389489187b857", 
    "ec136ea7349a087b1a2c45f68cff8bd30a142a4f07dce11879fa46936d401117", 
    "72497f475e4f76d0b28f57c73a084ece576d170874eba3ee2609d9afe4b71aab" 
  ], 
  [ 
    "ExternId123dfg",
    "27aceb96e275c3f80463f472d8cadf320c5a448d89b4aa9910d872601d569621", 
    "1369f121c02faf47c434c5e8abd28f44af7bd53ada021e6f71bc1af208edc6e7", 
    "08bce13e67535920d8229d8087e98c8715f886299c1a86fad0b78baf9406c2f2" 
  ] 
] 
}
```

This is basically Facebook's sample post. When I look at the FB ad account and look at this audiences audit history. No record of the upload call happening is there. But the "last updated" date is updated.

Here is the response I get back from the FB API.

```
{
  "audience_id": "{{my audience id}}",
  "session_id": "3347275067911290060",
  "num_received": 2,
  "num_invalid_entries": 0,
  "invalid_entry_samples": {}
}
```

This is a call I saved in PostMan and it has been working for weeks. Now all of a sudden it stopped working.

Comment: I too am having the same issue it looks like several cases have been opened with Facebook

Comment: Hi ToddB , @coder29 : facing the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution? I know it's been a while, but it seems like the issue persists

Comment: This issue went away in a later version of the API so I never got a good answer on this problem.